# how can i get all the datas that have same value from mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

in my database, there are two companies with same name.

```
[
  {
    "name": "samsung",
    "store_code": "34d"
  },
  {
    "name": "lg",
    "store_code": "333"
  },
  {
    "name": "lg",
    "store_code": "3511"
  }
]
```

like this..

my question is, I juse made my python function to get store information by name.

that looks like this..

```
async def fetch_store_by_name(store_name):
document = collection.find_one({"name":store_name})
return document
```

and I can only get the first lg company's information.
how can I get both informations of lg company from my mongodb?

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` instead of `find_one` .

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_find.asp

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you're using `pymongo`, just change `find_one` to `find` method. Like this:

```py
async def fetch_store_by_name(store_name):
  document = collection.find({"name":store_name})
  return document
```

Here some documentation : https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#querying-for-more-than-one-document

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collection.find({"name":store_name})`

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_find.asp

Answer (score 0):

Using variables such as name, address, zip code to identify a document is not a good approach as there may be the same names, names with different cases, spaces ex: LG, lg.

You can use the default mongo _id as a unique property to find the doc. Still you want to get the document then use `collection.find({"name":store_name})` it will returns multiple documents ab array. If you want to retrieve only one doc then use `collection.findOne({"name":store_name})`

Comment: thank you so much. but My company wants to search client;s information by company name since one company can have many stores and we need to get all those stores information. using unique id will be safer but since there must be same company names in db, we don't provide filtering by unique id. it's little frustrating